# Symfony2: login_check returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, symfony

I set the following security file:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/login$
            anonymous: ~
            security: false

        frontend:
            pattern: ^/*
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
              login_path: /login
              check_path: /login_check
              provider: main

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
    encoders:
        Printing\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: Printing\UserBundle\Entity\User
                property: name

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I also implemented a User class which implements UserInterface. But when I do a correct login, browser return me an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

- PHP Version => 5.5.9
- Intl enabled
- APC enabled

Comment: Usually the reason why PHP makes an httpd segfault (without leaving a core dump, I suppose) is a faulty extension in PHP, or a combination of two incompatible ones. Examples are:

    APC + XCache (or, in general two accelerators)
    suhosin + xdebug

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with it for a while, i noticed that the function getPassword of my User entity call itself instead of returning the password field.

Sorry for the inconvenience!